# Robocopy not functioning in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm having some trouble using RoboCopy.exe through a Powershell script. The function is as follows...

```
function copyFiles{
    Start-Process "RoboCopy.exe" -ArgumentList "'C:\Test' 'C:\test2' /copyall"
    Write-Host 'Test'
}
```

"Test" is output to console but the copy does not run. I was initially attempting to copy with variables as the directories, but I've boiled it down to this since that was not working. In the directory 'test1' there is a single .txt file and 'test2' exists but is empty. I have tried it without that directory existing as well.

It is called in another file via:

```
. .\rCopy.ps1
copyFiles
```

Now, I tried outputting the log to a file with the code below, but it gives me a permissions error. "Out-File : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop' is denied". I also tried outputting direct to C:\ but that gives the same error. Powershell IS running as administrator.

```
$testCopy = Start-Process "RoboCopy.exe" -ArgumentList "'C:\Test' 'C:\test2' /copyall"
$testCopy | Out-File -LiteralPath "C:\Users\Me\
```

And to close, I have also tried running "Start-Process 'RoboCopy.exe' -ArgumentList 'C:\test' 'C:\test2' /copyall" in the main script, without calling the function from another.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested the robocopy syntax outside of powershell? Does the destination directory already exists? Out-File requires a filename, not a path. Make sure you have rights to copy files to destination, or in this case c:

Comment: As an aside: Your use of `Start-Process` may be intentional to run `RocoCopy.exe` _asynchronously_, in a _new window_, but the more typical case is to execute console applications _synchronously_, in the _same window_, in which case you need to call them _directly_ (`c:\path\to\some.exe ...` or `& $exePath ...`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).  An alternative to asynchronous execution in a new window is to use a [background job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by using the following syntax:

```
Start-Process "RoboCopy.exe" -argumentlist "`"$localDir`" `"$networkDir`"  "
```

I cannot copy from the directory I've been trying to from the get-go, but I'm assuming that's a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your [own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60251665/45375) is effective: **quoted arguments passed to *external programs* such as `Robocopy.exe` inside a (single) `-ArgumentList` argument require embedded *double* quotes (`"`), not *single* quotes (`'`)**.

Generally, external programs do *not* recognize `'` as string delimiters on the command line, and that even applies to calling PowerShell itself via its CLI's `-File` parameter.

Even if you were to pass the arguments *one by one* to `-ArgumentList`:

```bash
# Note the individual arguments.
# !! Works in this case, but with paths that have *embedded spaces*
# !! you  would still need embedded "..." quoting.
Start-Process Robocopy.exe -ArgumentList 'C:\Test', 'C:\test2', '/copyall'
```

you'd still have to use embedded `"..."` quoting in *individual* arguments that (may) contain *embedded spaces* (e.g., `'"C:\Test 1"'` or, with a variable reference, `` "`"$dir`"" ``, due to a long-standing bug that won't be fixed for the sake of backward compatibility - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973199/45375) for background information.