# PowerShell script add '--prod' argument to build Angular CLI project

Tags: angular, powershell, angular-cli

I am creating PowerShell script to automatically build Angular CLI project.
When I use this command in my .ps1 file:

```
Start-Process -FilePath ng build -WorkingDirectory D:\pathToAngularProject -Wait
```

it works perfectly but create not uglified javascript build. To be able to create production build I need to add '--prod' argument.
But when I change example above on :

```
Start-Process -FilePath ng build -ArgumentList '--prod' -WorkingDirectory D:\pathToAngularProject -Wait
```

I am getting the error:
[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion how can I add an argument to 'ng build' command in PowerShell script?

Comment: What is `ng build`? If it is a file, surround it in quotes `"ng build"` if it is an argument, add it to the argument list `-ArgumentList '--prod', 'build'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Neko Musume's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671858/neko-musume) provides a solution to your immediate problem.

However, it's worth taking a step back:

**To synchronously execute console applications or batch files, call them *directly* (`ng build ...` or `& ng build ...`), do *not* use `Start-Process`** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) and [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) detailing appropriate vs. non-appropriate use cases and requesting that guidance be added to the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) help topic.

Therefore:

```bash
# Execute ng synchronously, with its output streams connected to PowerShell's
ng build --prod D:\pathToAngularProject
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

To add to Neko's answer:

The reason that your first command worked is that the following:

```bash
Start-Process -FilePath ng build
```

is equivalent to:

```bash
Start-Process -FilePath -FilePath ng -ArgumentList build
```

That is, the `build` argument was bound *positionally*, without the need to name its target parameter, `-ArgumentList`, explicitly.

Taking advantage of this, and also that `-FilePath` is implied for the *first* positional argument, the immediate solution to your problem could be simplified to:

```bash
# The 1st positional argument, 'ng', binds to -FilePath
# The 2nd positional argument, the *array* of arguments to pass to 'ng',
# 'build' and '--prod', binds to -ArgumentList
Start-Process ng  build, --prod
```

That said, **`Start-Process` has a long-standing *bug* that causes it to pass arguments *with embedded spaces* incorrectly** - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576).
To preserve backward compatibility, this bug will likely not get fixed (except perhaps by [introducing a *new parameter*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576#issuecomment-666566501)).

**It is therefore preferable to pass the arguments as a *single* array element, effectively as a *command line* (without the executable) encoding *all* arguments**, where the boundaries between the arguments can properly be signaled with **embedded *double*-quoting (`"..."`)**, if necessary:

```bash
# Pass the arguments for 'ng' *as a single string*, potentially
# with embedded "..." quoting (not needed here).
Start-Process ng  'build --prod'
```

An example with embedded quoting:

```bash
# Project path needs embedded "..." quoting, because it contains spaces.
Start-Process ng  'build --prod "D:\Work Projects\Foo"' ...
```

An example that uses an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) in order to embed the values of variables / subexpressions (the *embedded* `"` chars. must then be escaped as `` `" `` (or `""`)):

```bash
$projDir = 'D:\Work Projects'
Start-Process ng  "build --prod `"$projDir\Foo`"" ...
```

---

**A general note on *quoting array elements***:

Because *command arguments* in PowerShell are parsed using the so-called *argument (parsing) mode* (shell-like), the (string) elements of the (implied) `-ArgumentList` do *not* generally require *quoting*.

That is, array `build, --prod` in *argument mode* is the equivalent of `'build', '--prod'` in *expression mode* (programming-language-like).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779223/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's parsing modes.

However, you may use the quoted form in argument mode too, and - depending on the element values - you may *have to* quote, such as when elements contain spaces or other shell metacharacter; additionally, if the *first* element looks like a *PowerShell* parameter name (e.g., `-prod` rather than `--prod`), it must be quoted too.

A few **examples**:

Note: For simplicity, `Write-Output` is used in the examples, which simply echoes each array element on its own line. An array passed to *any* cmdlet is parsed in *argument mode*.

```bash
# No quoting needed.
# Elements contain no PowerShell metacharacters.
Write-Output one, two

# Quoting needed for the 2nd array element, due to containing
# PowerShell metacharacters (space, parentheses)
Write-Output one, 'two (2)'

# Quoting needed for the 1st array element, because it looks
# like a PowerShell parameter name.
# (Of course, you may choose to quote *both* elements in this case,
# for consistency).
Write-Output '-one', two

# If the parameter-like argument isn't the *first* array element,
# the need for quoting goes away
Write-Output one, -two
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `build` to the `-argumentlist` if it is an argument like:

```
Start-Process -FilePath ng -ArgumentList 'build', '--prod' -WorkingDirectory D:\pathToAngularProject -Wait
```

If it is part of the path quote it in the `-path` parameter because there are spaces:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "ng build" -ArgumentList '--prod' -WorkingDirectory D:\pathToAngularProject -Wait
```

Comment: The executable is `ng` by itself, which is the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/). However, it's worth pointing out that `Start-Process` is usually the wrong tool for invoking CLIs (console applications).

Comment: Also, while `-ArgumentList` _should_ be the proper way to pass arguments through individually, it unfortunately isn't in the general case, due to a longstanding bug (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576)) - since the arguments in this particular case contain no spaces, the command works, however.