# Arguments in powershell

Tags: powershell

I havent used powershell a lot, so i am running into an issue with the argument `GROUPING_TAGS`. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here? It works if i remove the grouping_tag argument.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$file = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test.exe"
$command = "Start-Process $file @('/install', '/quiet', '/norestart', 'CID=xxxxxxxxxxxx-123', 'GROUPING_TAGS=”Apple,Banana”')"
 
Invoke-Expression $command
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using `Invoke-Expression` instead of calling `Start-Process` directly?

Comment: You are using curly quotes in `GROUPING_TAGS`. Why not use straight double quotes and escape them? --> `'GROUPING_TAGS=""Apple,Banana""'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - thanks for the suggestion, i will try that out. I am still not very familiar with powershell. What is the drawback of calling `Invoke-Expression` into the `Start-Process`?

Comment: @OK999 As you've just found out, it means you need to doubly escape strings. It also obscures error details (should an error occur), and it opens you up to injection attacks if you ever decide to include caller-controlled input of any kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**:

- `Invoke-Expression` should generally be *avoided* and used only as a *last resort*, due to its inherent security risks. In short: Avoid it, if possible, given that superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).
- Unless you want to execute `test.exe` *asynchronously*, in a *new window*, also do not use `Start-Process` - use direct invocation instead (`& $file ....`); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375) for more information.

---

In your case, call `Start-Process` directly, with a *single* (positionally implied) `-ArgumentList` / `-Args` argument string containing *all* arguments:

```
$file = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test.exe"
Start-Process $file '/install /quiet /norestart CID=xxxxxxxxxxxx-123 GROUPING_TAGS="Apple,Banana"'
```

Note: It is a *bug* in `Start-Process` that makes passing all arguments as a single string rather than as an array of individual arguments preferable, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375).

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. had to to put a back ticks infront of the "

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 2.0
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$file = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test.exe"
$command = "Start-Process $file @('/install', '/quiet', '/norestart', 'CID=xxxxxxxxxxxx-123', 'GROUPING_TAGS=`”Apple,Banana`”')"
 
Invoke-Expression $command
```

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` should generally be _avoided_ and used only as a _last resort_, due to its inherent security risks. In short: Avoid it, if possible, given that superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).