# Powershell start-process issue when path contains R character after parenthesis

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install msi from commandline using powershell command. My msi path contains R character after parenthesis. Due to this powershell throws below error.

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Start-Process -Wait -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i, `"c:\program files\xxx (R) xxx.msi`"
```

[image]

If my path contain no parenthesis, it is working fine. Can someone help me resolve this issue.
Do not suggest some other method to do it. I would like to know the path issue as it works when my msi path doesnt have parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

From PowerShell:

```sh
# Note that parameter -FilePath is implied for `msiexec`, and
# -ArgumentList for `'/i ...'`
Start-Process -Wait msiexec '/i "c:\program files\xxx (R) xxx.msi"'
```

The most robust approach is to use a *single* `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) argument that encodes *all* arguments, using embedded quoting, rather than passing arguments *individually*, due to a long-standing bug detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375).

---

From `cmd.exe`, there's no reason to involve PowerShell in this case; the built-in `start` command will do:

```sh
start /wait msiexec /i "c:\program files\xxx (R) xxx.msi"
```

---