# Powershell Script: Pass parameter with "" like $Arg="$somePath" should result in "c:\temp\" including the ""

Tags: powershell, parameters, escaping, double-quotes, external-script

this is my first question on stackoverflow, so please be easy on me.

Problem:
The call to an external EXE file from a Powershell Script should look like this.

```
C:\temp\someEXE.exe "batch" "B:\some path with spaces\file name with spaces.jpg" "" "C:\some other path"
```

My $Arguments Variable in the ps1-script looks like this.

```
$Arguments = '"batch"', "$Originalpath", '""', "$Outpath\$Outfile"
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Temp\SomeExe.exe" -ArgumentList "$Arguments"
```

Argument 1 "batch" and 3, the empty "" works fine with the '""' (single - double - double - single).

But when i use the '"$Variable"' (single-double  double-single) it is not interpreted according to the Quoting Rules (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1)

So my question is:
How do i get from $Originalpath to "B:\some path with spaces\file name with spaces.jpg" incl. the ""

Thank you in advance

UPDATE:
When i add a line to write the Parameters to a logfile, this line gives me what i need.

```
Write-output '"batch"',`"$Original`",'""',`"$AIAusgabepfad\$Originaldatei$Originaltyp`" | Out-file C:\Temp\Startup.log -append
```

But when i try to my $Arguments in the same way, the scriptwindow pops up and disapears in the same second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally:
**To synchronously execute *console* applications or *batch files*, call them *directly* (`C:\temp\someEXE.exe ...`), do *not* use `Start-Process`** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) and [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) detailing appropriate vs. non-appropriate use cases and requesting that guidance be added to the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) help topic.

- That said, note that, as of PowerShell 7.1, passing *empty-string* arguments (`""`) is broken and requires *workaround* `'""'`.
- Similarly, passing arguments with embedded `"` chars. is also broken, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375).
- An *opt-in* fix is now being discussed in [GitHub issue #14747](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14747), but note that if you opt into that fix, the old workarounds will *break*.

---

If you *do* need to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process):

While the `-ArgumentList` parameter is *array*-typed (`[string[]]`), allowing you to pass arguments *individually* - which you've tried to take advantage of - unfortunately, **`Start-Process` doesn't handle such individually passed arguments properly if they contain *embedded spaces*** (see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576)), so **the robust solution is to use a *single* `-ArgumentList` argument comprising *all* arguments, with *embedded double-quoting*, as necessary** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375) for a more detailed discussion).

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Temp\SomeExe.exe" -ArgumentList `
  "batch `"$Originalpath`" `"`" `"$Outpath\$Outfile`""
```

Note that this method of passing arguments - as a single string with embedded quoting and escaping passed to `Start-Process -ArgumentList` - is *not* subject to the bugs that plague *direct* invocation: the resulting string is passed through to the process as-is (on Windows).

Comment: Thank you for the right direction.
I need the Start-Process because i need the -wait option to limit the number of concurent runs. 

I tried to pass the arguments directly (and not via the $Arguments Variable)

This is the version that is working for me now. 

Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Temp\SomeEXE.exe" -ArgumentList '"batch"',`"$Originalpath`",'""',`"$Outpath\$Outfile`"

Comment: @JürgenMayr, yes, if the application is a GUI-subsystem application, you need `Start-Process -Wait` to execute it synchronously (with console-subsystem applications, invocation is synchronous by default). The command you're showing would break if any of the values contained in the references variables contained _spaces_ (which is the bug that the answer links to) - passing everything as a _single_ `-ArgumentList` argument with _embedded quoting_, as shown in the answer, avoids that.