# powershell start-process doesn't accept two commands in ArgumentList because they have a same parameter

Tags: powershell

I want to launch a admin powershell with two commands :

```
$command1 = "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{example}' -Name DHCPClassId -Value National"
$command2 = "Restart-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet"
Start-Process powershell -Verb 'RunAs' -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command &{$command1,$command2}"
```

And i have an error : he don't want to execute these two because they have a same parameter (`-Name`), so, what can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerShell's statement separator is `;`**, not `,` (the latter [constructs arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-)).

Also:

- Even though passing arguments individually, as elements of an *array* to `Start-Process` is conceptually clean, it should be avoided due to a long-standing bug: pass a *single* string encoding *all* arguments to `-ArgumentList` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375) for more information.
- When using PowerShell's CLI, `-Command & { ... }` is never necessary - just use `-Command ...`; that is, there is no reason to construct a script block (`{ ... }`) that you must then invoke with `&` - all commands given are *directly* executed by default.

To put it all together:

```
$command1 = "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{example}' -Name DHCPClassId -Value National"
$command2 = "Restart-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet"
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs "-NoExit -Command $command1; $command2"
```