# Powershell Elevated and pass a command

Tags: powershell

So I am building a script that launches an executable in the common files folder of x86 folder. The issue I am having is the script uses the (x86) as if the x86 is a command that should be run first. Does anyone have any ideas on how to prevent that?

```
$Pulse = "${env:CommonProgramFiles(x86)}\Pulse Secure\JamUI\JamCommand.exe"
$ImportFile = '"-importfile "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyFile.preconfig"'
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-noprofile", "-command &{Start $Pulse, $ImportFile}" -Verb Runas
```

Comment: Why are you launching an intermediary `powershell.exe` process? Why not just `Start-Process $Pulse ... -Verb RunAs` directly?

Answer (score 1):

As Mathias notes, there is no strict need to launch another *PowerShell* instance with elevation (run as admin, `-Verb RunAs`), because you can directly elevate the target executable, `JamCommand.exe`; however, if you want to run the executable in another PowerShell session that *stays open* afterwards - as your use of `-noexit` suggests - you indeed do:

```sh
$pulse = "${env:CommonProgramFiles(x86)}\Pulse Secure\JamUI\JamCommand.exe"
$importFileArg = '-importfile "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyFile.preconfig"'

Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell @"
 -noexit -noprofile -c & "$pulse" $importFileArg
"@
```

Note:

- This runs `JamCommand.exe` directly in the elevated PowerShell session, synchronously (assuming it is a console application), and the interactive session is only entered *after* that program exits. (Your attempt contains another `Start-Process` call (via alias `Start`), which would make a console program run in yet another console window, which auto-closes when the program exits.)
- All pass-through arguments are encoded in a *single* (here)-string passed to the (positionally implied) `-ArgumentList` parameter, which allows direct control of the command line that is used to launch process, and is generally the most robust approach due to a long-standing bug in how passing arguments *individually*, as elements of an *array* is handled - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375).