# Passing multi-line KQL query to Az PowerShell cmdlet - error parsing query

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

Trying to pass a KQL string as parameter to cmdlet inside an Azure Automation Powershell 5.1 Runbook. But seems here-doc is giving error.

Please note need to avoid error-prone way of escaping each characters as it is cumbersome each time to modify back & forth the query.

Full query can be [found here](https://github.com/globalbao/azure-resource-graph#query-azure-security-benchmark-compliance-across-all-subscriptions):

```
$query1 = @"
... multi-line KQL query...
"@

$output = Search-AzGraph -Query $query1
```

This throws error:

```
Search-AzGraph : {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Please provide below info when asking for support: timestamp = 2023-03-13T14:58:53.0156938Z, correlationId =
XXXX.XXX",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "InvalidQuery",
        "message": "Query is invalid. Please refer to the documentation for the Azure Resource Graph service and fix the error before retrying."
      },
      {
        "code": "ParserFailure",
        "message": "ParserFailure",
        "line": 1,
        "characterPositionInLine": 3815,
        "token": "."
      }
    ]
  }
}
At line:1 char:11
+ $output = Search-AzGraph -Query $the_query
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Search-AzGraph], ErrorResponseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadRequest,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceGraph.Cmdlets.SearchAzureRmGraph
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Your query string](https://github.com/globalbao/azure-resource-graph#query-azure-security-benchmark-compliance-across-all-subscriptions) contains tokens such as `$right` and `$left` (`$right.controlId == $left.complianceControlId`)
- You're using the `@"<newline>...<newline>@"` to enclose your query string, i.e, the *expandable* (interpolating), *double-quoted* form of a PowerShell [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings).

  - Therefore, it is *PowerShell* that expands tokens such as `$right` in your query string, *before* you pass it on. (It replaces `$right` with the *value* of that PowerShell variable; if none is defined, `$right` expands to the *empty string*.)
- If that is undesired, use `@'<newline>...<newline>'@`, i.e. the *verbatim*, *single-quoted* here-string form.

  - If you need to *combine* PowerShell's string expansion with *pass-through* `$` characters, use `@"<newline>...<newline>@"` and escape the pass-through `$` as `` `$ ``

---

Assuming that you want a *verbatim* query string:

```bash
$query1 = @'
... multi-line KQL query...
'@

$output = Search-AzGraph -Query $query1
```