# How to install msi with a script

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I am having an issue with Windows Installer popup when running my script.

My script

```
function InstallMyMsi {
    $File='C:\\my\\path\\my msi file.msi'
    $DT = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmm"
    $Log = "C:\\my\\other_path\\Log_$DT.log"
    
    $Params = "/L*V $Log", '/i', $File, '/qn!', '/quiet', '/passive'
    $p = Start-Process `
        'msiexec.exe' `
        -ArgumentList $Params `
        -NoNewWindow `
        -Wait `
        -PassThru

    return $p.ExitCode
}

InstallMyMsi
```

I have tried different combinations of arguments with no luck.

Any ideas?

Edit:
The file name of the msi contains space. I have edited that part, could this be the cause of the issue?

Comment: PowerShell does not need for you to escape the \.  Change \\ to \ in $File and $Log

Comment: (Daniel is correct, but the double backlashes are benign and don't explain your problem.) If the pop-up dialog is the standard dialog explaining the _command-line syntax_, the implication is that your `msiexec` call has a _syntax problem_.

Comment: As an aside: While passing the pass-through arguments _individually_ to `-ArgumentList` may be conceptually preferable, a [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) unfortunately makes it better to encode all arguments in a _single string_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375).

Comment: I have made the changes as per suggestion, but the issue still persists. I managed to get it to run when I replaced space with an underscore. But I don't understand why this works

Comment: Is `/qn!` a valid switch or should it just be `/qn`?

Comment: /qn! is not valid.  I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this before.  It's often easier to build a string and pass it that way.  Also, you may need to surround your argument to /i with quotes as some paths to your installer may have a space it in.

```
function InstallMyMsi {
    $File='C:\\my\\path\\file.msi'
    $DT = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmm"
    $Log = "C:\\my\\other_path\\Log_$DT.log"

    $Params = "/L*V $Log /i `"$File`" /qn /quiet /passive"
    $p = Start-Process `
        'msiexec.exe' `
        -ArgumentList $Params `
        -NoNewWindow `
        -Wait `
        -PassThru

    return $p.ExitCode
}

InstallMyMsi
```