# Run a PowerShell script from a cmd batch as admin

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, elevated-privileges, executionpolicy

I have a PowerShell setup which I want to execute on a computer where perhaps the execution policy is restricted and requires admin rights.
Ideally, I could wrap it in a cmd batch like follows:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList '-noexit','-ExecutionPolicy','bypass','-File','C:\path\setup.ps1'"
```

The problem is that I can't make it to work when `C:\path\setup.ps1` contains spaces, and also the path does not work if relative (with `cd C:\path`).
Any help?

Comment: Are you running the batch file as admin already?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala: No. The whole purpose of  the cmd batch is to ask the user to elevate and to temporarily allow script execution. Hence, the arguments `-Verb runAs` and `ExecutionPolicy bypass`.

Comment: I'm aware of the arguments, was just trying to provide an alternate solution while getting more context.

Comment: Why is Cmd needed to run the script? Why not use a self-elevating full PowerShell script?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon if the execution policy is restricted you cannot execute a self elevating script in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In ***Windows PowerShell*** (see bottom section for *PowerShell (Core) 7+*), using **`Start-Process -Verb RunAs`** to launch a command *with elevation* (as admin), ***invariably* uses `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32`  as the working directory** - even a `-WorkingDirectory` argument, if present, is quietly ignored.
  Thus, in order to set a custom working directory and to invoke a script there, the `-Command` CLI parameter must be used, and a [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) (`cd`) call must precede a call to a script specified by *relative* path.
- While passing the pass-through arguments *individually* to the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet's  `-ArgumentList` parameter may be conceptually preferable, a [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) unfortunately makes it **better to encode all arguments in a *single string*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375).
- Doing all this from `cmd.exe`, via `powershell.exe`, the Windows PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe),  complicates matters due to escaping requirements.

Applied to your [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) CLI call,
assuming working dir. `C:\path 1` and script file `setup 1.ps1`:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell '-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command cd \\\"C:\path 1\\\"; & \\\".\setup 1.ps1\\\"' "
```

- Note how the embedded `"` chars. are *doubly* escaped, as `\\\"`: first as `\"` in order to be preserved during the *outer* `powershell.exe` call, and then again for the *inner* one.
- While this *typically* works, there are *edge cases* where `\`-based escaping is *not* enough, namely if the script path or file name contains a *`cmd.exe`* metacharacter, such as `&`; in that case, `"^""` (sic) must be used for the first round of `"`-escaping:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell '-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "^"" cd \\"^""C:\path 1\\"^""; & \\"^"".\setup 1.ps1\\"^"" "^""'"
```

Note:

- *From `cmd.exe` (batch files)*, `"^""` (sic) is the most robust way to pass `"` that are embedded in an overall `"..."` string to `powershell.exe`, as shown above, whereas it is `""` for [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI (see below).
- By contrast, from a *shell-free* context (e.g., a scheduled task) `\"` works robustly, in both editions.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for details.

---

When you call **`pwsh.exe`** instead - the **PowerShell (Core) 7+ [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh)** - simplifications are possible and a workaround may not even be needed:

- **`pwsh.exe` *does* preserve the caller's working directory by default even with `-Verb RunAs`** and *does* respect a `-WorkingDirectory` argument with `-Verb RunAs`.
- **In addition to `\"`**, `pwsh.exe` more simply **supports `""`** for embedding `"` chars. in `"..."` strings; the latter works robustly from `cmd.exe`
- **`pwsh.exe` itself now has a `-WorkingDirectory` parameter**, which therefore allows invoking the script with the `-File` parameter:

```
pwsh.exe -WorkingDirectory "C:\path 1" -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs pwsh.exe '-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\path 1\setup 1.ps1""'"
```

Comment: Thank you. Your `"^""` solved the issue. Still sad to observe how, despite all their efforts, Microsoft is unable to give us a simple syntax to call an admin script. Something that in Linux would be as simple as `sudo '/path/to/setup'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example of a script that checks if the process is running elevated and if it's not it attempts to start a new process elevated. There is no need to nest files or use CMD in this case.

This obviously comes with the caveat of an UAC prompt, as any other process that is started with elevated permissions.

```
$isAdmin = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]::new(
    [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).
        IsInRole('Administrators')

if(-not $isAdmin) {
    $params = @{
        FilePath     = 'powershell' # or pwsh if Core
        Verb         = 'RunAs'
        ArgumentList = @(
            '-NoExit'
            '-ExecutionPolicy ByPass'
            '-File "{0}"' -f $PSCommandPath
        )
    }

    Start-Process @params
    return
}

"I'm elevated"
# Code goes here
```

Comment: Thank you, but, as mentioned in the question, I do not know in advance what the execution policies on the target computers could possibly be, and they could be set to restricted.