# Running Batch File To Execute PowerShell and Additional Batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have the following in a Powershell script - InstallApp.ps1 - to download an executable, then install the executable, and finally, to run a batch file to apply the necessary configurations within the app:

```
#Change directory to script location
    CD $PSScriptRoot

#Download Application
    $AppSource = "www.url.com/application.exe;
    $AppDestination = "$PSScriptRoot\application.exe"
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Invoke-WebRequest -URi $AppSource -OutFile $AppDestination

#Install Application

    .\application.exe --platform minimal --script silent-install.js InstallDir=C:\Application

#Configure Application

    Start-Process .\ConfigureApp.bat -Verb RunAs

    Write-host "Configuring Application. Do not proceed until addittional Command Prompt window closes"

    Pause
```

If I open PowerShell as Administrator and run this script, everything works without issue. The problem is, I need to pass this on and have other people run it as admin. My go to in this situation is to create a batch file called _RunMeAsAdmin.bat and include it in the package.  With that I will have:

```
@echo off

:: Install App
cd /D "%~dp0"
Powershell.exe -ep bypass -file InstallApp.ps1 -Verb RunAs
```

When I run this, the Powershell script goes all the way through installing the application, but never calls the additional ConfigureApp.bat to finalize the configurations.

I realize this is probably a roundabout way of accomplishing what I want, but curious if anyone has any input on how I can get this to work?

Comment: If PowerShell is already running elevated then `-Verb RunAs` is unnecessary when launching the batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`powershell.exe`, the Windows PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), doesn't *directly* support `-Verb RunAs` in order to launch a process with elevation (as admin).

Instead, you must use use the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter to pass a command that calls [`Start-Process -Verb RunAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), which in turn requires a *nested* `powershell.exe` call in order to execute the `.ps1` file with elevation:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -c Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-ep bypass -file \"%CD%\InstallApp.ps1\"'
```

Note:

- Since `-Verb RunAs` in Windows PowerShell makes the elevated process default to the SYSTEM32 directory instead of the caller's, the `.ps1` file path was explicitly prefixed with the caller's working directory, `%CD%`.

  - Note: Since your `.ps1` script explicitly sets its own working directory (`CD $PSScriptRoot`), there is no need to preset the working directory for the elevated process.
  - Doing so would complicate the call, because you cannot simply use the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter of `Start-Process` in combination with `-Verb RunAs`. Instead, you'd have to switch the nested `powershell.exe` call to a `-Command` (`-c`) invocation that executes `Set-Location` (`cd`) *in the elevated process*, before calling the target script, which complicates quoting and escaping - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70736235/45375) for an example.
- I've omitted `-ep bypass` from the *outer* `powershell.exe` call, as it isn't necessary there (only a *cmdlet*  - `Start-Process` - is executed in its session, which isn't subject to the effective execution policy).

  - However, I've substituted `-noprofile` to suppress execution of any [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) scripts - which *are* subject to the execution policy.
  - Routine use of `-noprofile` is advisable for automated execution, both for a more predictable execution environment and to eliminate unnecessary processing.
- Add `-Wait` to the `Start-Process` call if you want to wait for the elevated script to exit.
- Since your `.ps1` script is then elevated via the batch file, you don't need `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` *inside the script* anymore, and you can simply place a 
  [`#Requires -RunAsAdministrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Requires#-runasadministrator) line at the start to prevent direct, non-elevated execution.

Finally, as an alternative to using a helper batch file, consider making your `.ps1` script *self-elevating*, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69775592/45375) (the linked answer is complex, because it tries to provide a generic, robust solution that supports arbitrary arguments; for argument-less invocations it can be greatly simplified).