# How to set private key as environment variable in powershell

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have assigned output of aws command to a variable:

```
$SECRET_KEY = (aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:12345:secret:non-prod/testing/private-key-8PPof --query 'SecretString' --output text)
```

Now i want to export the output of this to environment variable.

if i use below

`$env:SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY` >> output formatting is messed up and everything is coming in one line with spaces for the key instead of newline

Can anyone help with how to export the output of the aws command as environment variable to the powershell cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Environment variables are invariably *strings*.
- In PowerShell, if you assign a value other than a string, that value is automatically *stringified* (converted to a string)

  - PowerShell reports stdout output from external programs such as `aws` as a *stream of lines*, which when *captured*, become an *array* of strings (lines).
  - PowerShell stringifies arrays by joining their elements with a single space as the separator,<sup>[1]</sup> which explains what you saw; a simple example:

    ```bash
    $arr = 1, 2; "$arr" # -> '1 2'
    ```
- **In order to assign a *multiline* string to an environment variable based on output from an external program, you'll have to join the lines *explicitly* with a newline as the separator**.

Therefore:

```bash
$env:SECRET_KEY = 
 (
   aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:12345:secret:non-prod/testing/private-key-8PPof --query 'SecretString' --output text
 ) -join "`n"
```

Note: The above uses Unix-format LF-only newlines (`` "`n" ``); to use Windows-format CRLF newlines, use `` "`r`n" ``

---

<sup>[1] The - rarely used - [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs) can *normally* be used to change the default separator. Curiously, however, it has *no* effect on the implicit stringification that happens on assigning to an environment variable.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help with this. 
Is there anyway we can set the output as a system wide environment variable rather than assigning it to $env:SECRET_KEY is only for that particular shell.

I have used this ```[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('DB_DRIVER', 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)```

Can we set the output of aws command directly to the sytem environment variable ?

Comment: @Springhills, yes, you can enclose the ``(...) -join "`n"`` call in `(...)` and use it directly as an argument in the `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` call. However, note that such a call (which fundamentally works on Windows only) updates the _persistent_ definition of the environment variable for _future_ sessions. If you also want it for the _current_ session (process), set `$env:SECRET_KEY` as shown in the answer and then pass `$env:SECRET_KEY` to  `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`

Comment: Hi @mklement0
I want that variable to be persist for that machine using as userdata script for new windows machine spin up

Can you please give the full syntax to use. Did not get how to add system environment variable. should i do something like below

```$env:SECRET_KEY = 
 (
   aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:12345:secret:non-prod/testing/private-key-8PPof --query 'SecretString' --output text
 ) -join "`r`n"
System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('SECRET_KEY', '$env:SECRET_KEY', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)```

Comment: @Springhills, replace `'$env:SECRET_KEY'` with `$env:SECRET_KEY` - whatever is inside `'...'` is used _verbatim_. Note that you'll need elevation (running as admin) for your call.

Comment: Thank you again.. life saver.. it works fine.
If its not too much to ask.. need one more help. trying to run powershell script as userdata so i started with <powershell> </powershell>
How to run it as administrator when spinning up new windows machine and trigger this user data script as administrator ?

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Springhills: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71471730/45375) helps.