# How to pass a variable to new console window in Powershell

Tags: powershell, start-process

I want to pass a variable to a new console, but I don't know how.

```
$server = "server_name"
Start-Process Powershell {
      $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = “Get-Process”
      Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
             Get-Process
      }
cmd /c pause
}
```

Error message:

Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again

Comment: Why is it important that `Invoke-Command` is called from a child process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) only accepts (one or more) *strings* as arguments, not a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`).

  - While a script block is *accepted*, it is simply *stringified*, which results in its *verbatim* content being passed as the argument (sans `{` and `}`), which means that `$server` is retained *as-is* (not expanded), and the child process that runs your command doesn't have a variable by that name defined, causing `Invoke-Command` to fail due not receiving a value for `-ComputerName`.
- Therefore, **in order to incorporate variable values from the caller's scope, you must use *string interpolation*, using an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)** that encodes all arguments:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
$server = "server_name"
# Parameters -FilePath and -ArgumentList are positionally implied.
# For the resulting powershell.exe call, -Command is implied.
Start-Process powershell "
  $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'Get-Process'
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Get-Process }
  pause
"
```

A computer name (`$server`, in your case) doesn't contain spaces, but any variable values that do would require *embedded* enclosing quoting inside the overall `"..."` string, such as `` \`"$someVar\`" `` (`` `" `` escapes an `"` inside a `"..."` string in PowerShell, and the `\` is additionally needed to escape the resulting verbatim `"` for the PowerShell *CLI*, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)).

For full robustness, additionally enclose the entire string value (implied `-Command` argument) in embedded `"..."` quoting (`` "`"...`"" ``).

You can make this a bit easier by using the [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) form of an expandable string (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`), inside of which you don't need to escape `"` chars.

Example of a **fully robust call**:

```
$someVar = 'A value with   spaces'
Start-Process powershell @"
  -NoProfile -Command "
    # Echo the value of $someVar
    Write-Output \"$someVar\"
    pause
  "
"@
```

Note the use of `-NoProfile` before `-Command`, which suppresses loading of the [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), which can speed up the call and makes for a more predictable execution environment.

---

<sup>[1] Technically, `-ArgumentList` accepts an *array* of arguments, and while passing the pass-through arguments *individually* may be conceptually preferable, a [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) unfortunately makes it better to encode all arguments in a *single string* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use param-

[info](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/powershell-abcs-p-is-for-parameters)

```
param([type]$p1 = , [type]$p2 = , ...)
```

or:

[info](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/technet-magazine/jj554301(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

```
param(
[string]$server 
)

Write-Host $a

./Test.ps1 "your server name"
```