# How to resolve powershell errors when installing react-native-windows in windows 11

Tags: reactjs, react-native, powershell, powershell-4.0, windows-11

I got a new system running on windows 11 and I'm having issues running the shell script to set up react native windows environment.

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force;
iex (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://aka.ms/rnw-deps.ps1')
Please I need help resolving this error.

The script can be found at https://aka.ms/rnw-deps.ps1
Error is from lines 68 and 130

Here's a screenshot of the error I'm getting.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [script you link to](https://aka.ms/rnw-deps.ps1) is broken (as of this writing):

Line 98:

```
Write-Debug No Retail versions of Visual Studio found, trying pre-release...
```

This line causes a syntax error, due to missing quoting; the correct syntax is:

```
Write-Debug 'No Retail versions of Visual Studio found, trying pre-release...'
```

Line 130:

```
$p = Start-Process -PassThru -Wait  -FilePath $vsInstaller -ArgumentList ("modify --channelId $channelId --productId $productId $addWorkloads --quiet --includeRecommended" -split ' ')
```

The fact that this line fails indicates that at least one of the referenced variables - `$channelId`, `$productId`, `$addWorkloads` is unexpectedly `$null`.

As an aside:

- That an *error* results from this is a manifestation of a *Windows PowerShell bug* (which has since been fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+) - passing an empty array or `$null` or an array that has at least one `$null` element to the `-ArgumentList` property of [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) unexpectedly causes an error.
- There is a separate `Start-Process` bug - still present as of PowerShell Core 7.2.2 - the workaround for which makes it better to pass all arguments *as a single string* with *embedded `"..."` quoting* (as needed) to `-ArgumentList` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375)):

  ```
  $p = Start-Process -PassThru -Wait  -FilePath $vsInstaller -ArgumentList "modify --channelId $channelId --productId $productId $addWorkloads --quiet --includeRecommended"
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed it, I raised an issue on GitHub and a commit has been made to remove the bug. The bug on line 130 was due to a previously unfinished install of "visual studio" by chocolatey.

Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Uwem, thanks for the update.