# Pass Arguments as Command Line Params Using Powershell's Start-Job cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use the Start-Job cmdlet to run a background job with parameters. The problem I'm faced with is that parameters passed in as a string won't get passed to the external program correctly.

This code fails:

```
$params = "/n 5 google.com"
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param([string]$p) ping.exe $p} -ArgumentList $params
```

This is a less than desireable workaround that does work:

```
$params = "/n 5 google.com"
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param([string]$p) Start-Process ping.exe -ArgumentList $p -Wait} -ArgumentList $params
```

The workaround is only less that desireable because I think Start-Process does something in the background with the processes which impacts my ability to kill any child processes that are started. I'm not a powershell/scripting wizard, so I'm not sure.

I've discovered the following and I'm pretty sure it's why I'm having issues, but I don't know why it's happening or how to get around it:
The following code does what is expected:

```
& ping.exe /n 5 google.com
```

This code fails:

```
$params = "/n 5 google.com"
& ping.exe $params
```

Comment: you can store the arguments in an array: `$params = "/n", 5, "google.com"` and it will work. the `&` is not needed in this case. Any reason not to use `Test-Connection` ? It even has a `-AsJob` in Windows PowerShell

Comment: In short: In order to programmatically pass arguments to external programs, construct an _array_, with each parameter (option) name and parameter value / positional argument (operand) becoming its own element, as shown in Santiago's comment. You can _not_ use a _single string_ to encode _multiple_ arguments. The linked duplicate isn't about `Start-Job`, but the explanation equally applies. Use `$args` in the `Start-Job` script block instead of declaring a parameter: `Start-Job { ping.exe $args } -ArgumentList /n, 5, google.com`

Comment: It is only with `Start-Process`, specifically, that you _can_ pass a single string that encodes multiple arguments and - due to a long-standing bug that won't be fixed - it is actually preferable in that case; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375).