# I want to create my own autorun but only for specific files, for .ps1 files it cannot continue

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I want to run a few scripts automatically and I cannot use builtin functions as I do not use explorer.exe as a shell.
so I have my main tool, which runs as a shell and then integrated a function to launch my autorun-script.
Now my issue is, that if there is a .ps1 file it always waits for it to finish and doesnt continue at all. I want it to start it hidden and continue immidiately running other files in my directory.

my script (.cmd):

```
:: Loop through each file in the directory and start them
for %%F in (*.exe *.lnk *.cmd *.bat *.ps1) do (
    echo Starting %%F...
    if "%%~xF"==".ps1" (
        start /B cmd /c powershell -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %%F' -WindowStyle Hidden"
    ) else (
        start "" "%%F"
    )
)
```

Comment: You're using a shell (`CMD`) to start another shell (`PowerShell`) to start another instance of the second shell (`PowerShell`) again ... really?   I'd probably rather use a *.lnk file to start an initial PowerShell script and handle everything else in this initial script. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Per your own feedback, your approach *did* work, after all: It launched the nested, hidden PowerShell processes running your `*.ps1` scripts *asynchronously*.
- However, your command can be simplified to avoid the unnecessary `cmd /c` call:

  ```
  start /b powershell -c Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden powershell '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %%F'
  ```

  - If there's a chance that `%%F` contains *spaces* (or other PowerShell *metacharacters*):

    ```
    start /b powershell -c "Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden powershell '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"%%F\"'"
    ```
- If you're not concerned about the startup cost of the *initial, transitory* `powershell` instance, further simplification is possible (no need for `start`):

  ```
  powershell -c "Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden powershell '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"%%F\"'"
  ```

Note:

- In [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) calls, preceding `-c` (`-Command`) or `-f` (`-File`) with `-NoProfile` is a good habit to form, which bypasses loading of [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) and therefore both potentially speeds up execution and makes for a more predictable execution environment.

**Explanation**:

- `/b` tells `cmd.exe`'s built-in `start` command to run `powershell`, which is a *console* application, *without creating a new console window*.

  - This in effect makes it run in the *caller's* console window, and while without `/WAIT`, this has the potential to interfere with the caller's subsequent output, this isn't a concern here, given that the sole purpose of this `powershell` instance is to launch *another* PowerShell instance in a *hidden* window (see below).
- `-c` (`-Command`) allows passing an arbitrary piece of PowerShell code to the [`powershell` *CLI*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe).
- PowerShell's [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet allows launching an arbitrary process; by default:

  - it does so *asynchronously* (you can change that with `-Wait`)
  - in a *new window*, whose style/visibility you can control via the `-WindowStyle` parameter (alternatively, analogous to `cmd.exe`'s `/B` option, you can use `-NoNewWindow` instead, but that is rarely useful).
- *Pass-through* arguments for the process launched by `Start-Process` are passed *as a single string* (enclosed in `'...'`):

  - `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` ensures that execution of the `*.ps1` file being passed to `-File` is permitted, irrespective of the currently effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies).
    However, note that this override only works if the execution policy isn't controlled via *GPOs* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564847/45375) for details.
  - As an aside: While pass-through arguments (via the positionally implied `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter) may also be passed as an *array* of *individual* arguments, a [long-standing bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) unfortunately makes it better to encode all arguments in a *single string*, because it makes the situational need for *embedded* double-quoting explicit - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375).